# One Firebase account to receive Messages, another one for logging Event and Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have one Android app which is using Firebase Clouding Messaging and realtime database to receive messages and read configurations.
Now we want to add Event and Crashlytics logging but in another Firebase account project.

I checked Firebase doc, it is possible to use multiple projects but seems with limitations.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/
For database, it is fine because getInstance accepts FirebaseApp as a parameter.
For event and crashlytics, above page has a "Note: On Android and iOS, Analytics are only logged for the default app."
For messaging, it is not mentioned.

So that means we need to make event and crashlytics firebase project as default one, messaging and database as secondary project.

But on FirebaseMessaging API, I could not find a way to pass the FirebaseApp instance like what FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp) does.

So what should I do to let messaging using the secondary project? Or any other solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's not possible, because messages come in through (singleton) services that don't provide a callback that indicates which app the message came from.  It seems that the assumption is that messages come in through the default app.

Also, messages are routed through Play services, which requires that each app must have a unique application ID SHA-1 pair (which wouldn't be possible to set up in the Firebase console, as it enforces that uniqueness among all registered apps).